# jQuery if statement inside click function

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a click event inside of which I would like to load different divs according to what has been clicked:

```
var open = $('.open');
open.click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    overlay.fadeIn(400, function(){
        box.fadeIn(500);
        // if something load box2
        // if something load box3
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLDXS/

Open is a class given to the links which relate to box, box2 and box3.
How can I load the content for box2, would I have to use a specific class for each of them?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to write an `if` condition?

Comment: You need to post the html that corresponds to your posted code so we can help you

Comment: I know how to write one, but how specifically in this case to load either box1, or box2 or box3?

Comment: Please add your HTML code to the question

Comment: yo, check your DOM class `.open` is not there in HTML! `:)` how do you trigger click event?

Comment: it's in it now http://jsfiddle.net/bLDXS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
After looking at the fiddle, you'll have to give each clickable `<p>` an id, and load the corresponding box.

Html:

```
<p class="terms open" id="box1_clicker">I agree to the <a href="">terms and conditions.</a></p>
```

Js:

```
if($(this).attr("id")=="box1_clicker") {
    // do something
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLDXS/4/)

---

You could specify an id for each of the boxes, and then check inside the click which box's link was clicked, using [jquery's `parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
if($(this).parent().attr("id") == "box1") {
    //some code
}
else if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == "box2") {
    //some code
}
// so on
```

Answer (score 1):

> Open is a class given to the links which relate to box, box2 and box3. How can I load the >content for box2, would I have to use a specific class for each of them?

No, you can simply write your code with if statement:

```
var open = $('.open');
open.click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
    overlay.fadeIn(400, function(){
    box.fadeIn(500);
    if (cond1){ load box2 }
    else if (cond2) {load box3 }
});
```

Comment: would the condition 1 be another click event saying if you click on .box2(for example) do this.....

Comment: No the condition cannot be another click event. I think your question so not clear enough. From what it seems you want to distinguish between which div / box generated the even and based on that condition you want to show some UI manipulations. If that is that case then you can check for id with $("this").attr('id') if using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var open = $('.open');
open.click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    box= $(this).attr('rel');//get the rel of your clicked link.
    overlay.fadeIn(400, function(){
        $('#'+box).fadeIn(500);//fadein the div your link relates to if it is your div's id.

    });
```